# In selenium the send_keys function ignores spaces when used with VNC

Tags: python, selenium, vnc

Why is the send_keys function ignoring spaces in my python script? I used vnc on ubuntu/debian 10. Everything works correctly when I run the script on my computer, but all spaces disappear on vps with vnc. Error is in Google chrome.
`

```
element.send_keys("1 2 3")

result: "123"
```

`

Replacing the spaces with "Keys.SPACE" did not help me.

I tried adding two slashes `element.send_keys("John\\ Doe")`

Comment: Are selenium/chromedirver versions the same on your pc, and on your vps?

Comment: I changed the versions of the chrome driver, set 107, 106 and 108 - they all work the same. And selenium versions are the same 4.6.0

Comment: Are you sure you can input spaces in the target field? It might be issue of the website.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's a google search field

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the libs and instantiate actions:

```
# Needed libs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

# We create the driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
action = ActionChains(driver)
```

Then make click into your element with something like:

```
element.click()
```

Then send the keys like:

```
action.send_keys(departure).perform()
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to get this to work in Chrome. But spaces work fine in Firefox, so I'll have to use that. If someone finds the cause or solution to my problem, please write

Comment: This update could be shared as a comment instead.